# Show macchanger info in Conky?

Tags: conky

Is there a way to show macchanger info in conky?
I wrote a script that changes it on login, but I always double check when I start the computer using macchanger wlan0 -s

I would like to show the output of this command into conky, if possible :)

Thanks in advanced to anyone who can help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can run shell commands and show the output of them in conky:

Write in your conky config file:

```
TEXT
${execi 30 /path/to/your/command}
```

This executes your command every 30 seconds and shows the output. If you don't want the specific interval use this config value:

```
TEXT
${exec /path/to/your/command}
```